# Add fake device to Windows Device Manager

Tags: delphi, winapi

I try to add some string (fake device) to Windows Device Manager. I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
procedure AddSomeString(AHandle:THandle);
var
 vItem: TLVItemW;
 vPointer,vPointerText:Pointer;
 vNumberOfBytesRead,vProcessId: SIZE_T;
 vProcess: THandle;
 vBuffer: array[ 0..255 ] of Char;
begin
      GetWindowThreadProcessId( AHandle, @vProcessId );
      vProcess := OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, vProcessId );
      vPointer := VirtualAllocEx( vProcess, nil, 4096, MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );
      vPointerText := VirtualAllocEx( vProcess, nil,256,MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE );
      vBuffer := 'Test';
      with vItem do
       begin
        mask       := LVIF_TEXT;
        iItem      := 0;
        iSubItem   := 0;
        cchTextMax := SizeOf( vBuffer );
        pszText    := vPointerText;
       end;
    
      WriteProcessMemory( vProcess, vPointer, @vItem, SizeOf( TLVItemW ), vNumberOfBytesRead );
      WriteProcessMemory( vProcess, vPointerText, @vBuffer[ 0 ], SizeOf( vBuffer ), vNumberOfBytesRead );
    
      SendMessage( AHandle, LVM_INSERTITEM, 0, lparam( vPointer ) );
      SendMessage( AHandle, LVM_SETITEMTEXT, 0, lparam( vPointer ) );
    
      VirtualFreeEx(vProcess, vPointer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
      VirtualFreeEx(vProcess, vPointerText, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
      CloseHandle(vProcess);
end;
```

I am passing to the function handle of SysTreeView32, but
SendMessage is always = 0

Can anyone suggest a working example?

Comment: [`LVM_INSERTITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-insertitem) is a list-view message, but the control is a tree-view control. Perhaps you are looking for [`TVM_INSERTITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvm-insertitem)? Also, where is all error checking and error handling? You should verify the success of each API call, not only `SendMessage`.

Comment: Besides which, 'fake' devices would generally be created through the setup API, installing an actual driver rather than by creating a useless node in the device manager.

Comment: The prefix of a message is meaningful. `LVM` is a **L**ist**V**iew **M**essage, `TVM` is a **T**ree**V**iew **M**essage. Don't mix them up.

Comment: Are you writing a malware?

Comment: Could you please share the reason you want to add a fake device to Device Manager?

Comment: why would you do this?