# Add node to TreeView of another window

Tags: delphi, taskmanager

I am trying to add my entries to SysTreeView32 of someone else's window (for example Task Manager) using the following code:

```pascal
procedure AddSomeString( AHandle:THandle );
var
 vItem: TTVItem;
 lpis : TTVInsertStruct;
 vPointer, vPointerText: Pointer;
 vNumberOfBytesRead, vProcessId: SIZE_T;
 vProcess: THandle;
 vBuffer: array[ 0..255 ] of Char;
begin
 GetWindowThreadProcessId( AHandle, @vProcessId );
 vProcess := OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, vProcessId );

 vPointer := VirtualAllocEx( vProcess, nil, 4096, MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE );
 vPointerText := VirtualAllocEx( vProcess, nil, 256, MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE );

 vBuffer := 'Test';

 ZeroMemory( @vItem, SizeOf( TTVItem ) );
 with vItem do
  begin
   mask           := TVIF_TEXT or TVIF_IMAGE or TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE;
   cchTextMax     := SizeOf( vBuffer );
   pszText        := vPointerText;
   iImage         := 3;
   iSelectedImage := 3;
  end;

 lpis.hParent      := 0;
 lpis.hInsertAfter := 0;
 lpis.item         := vItem;

 WriteProcessMemory( vProcess, vPointer, @lpis, SizeOf( TTVInsertStruct ), vNumberOfBytesRead );
 WriteProcessMemory( vProcess, vPointerText, @vBuffer[ 0 ], SizeOf( vBuffer ), vNumberOfBytesRead );

 SendMessage( AHandle, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, LPARAM( vPointer ) );

 VirtualFreeEx( vProcess, vPointer    , 0, MEM_RELEASE );
 VirtualFreeEx( vProcess, vPointerText, 0, MEM_RELEASE );
 CloseHandle( vProcess );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 h: HWND;
begin
 h := FindWindow( nil, PChar( 'Диспетчер устройств' ) );
 h := FindWindowEx( h, 0, PChar( 'MDIClient' ), nil );
 h := FindWindowEx( h, 0, PChar( 'MMCChildFrm' ), nil );
 h := FindWindowEx( h, 0, PChar( 'MMCViewWindow' ), nil );
 h := FindWindowEx( h, 0, PChar( 'MMCOCXViewWindow' ), nil );
 h := FindWindowEx( h, 0, PChar( 'AtlAxWinEx' ), nil );
 h := FindWindowEx( h, 0, PChar( 'AfxOleControl42u' ), nil );
 h := FindWindowEx( h, 0, PChar( 'SysTreeView32' ), nil );

 if h <> 0 then
  begin
    AddSomeString( h );
    InvalidateRect( h, nil, False );
  end;
end;
```

The code does not contain function return checks for simplicity.

This code adds an entry to the root of the tree, but does not display the text and does not change the node icon:

[image]

Can anyone help me fix the code so that I can add my own entry, for example, to the item Processors?

Comment: Have a read on [Are there legitimate “fix my code” questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/4299358) and then tell us at which point your code's behaviour differs from your expectations.

Comment: I gave an example of the image of what is obtained in the output of this code. I need to add text to the created tree item and change the icon.

Comment: There is a complete lack of adequate error handling. For instance, you are asking for too many permissions from `OpenProcess()`, so it will likely fail. And you are not checking `VirtualAllocEx()` or `WriteProcessMemory()` for failure before calling `SendMessage()`. I know you left off error checking for simplicity, but you really can't do that. Error handling asside, your handling of the allocated memory could be done better. And your use of `SizeOf()` in several places is just plain wrong if you are using Delphi 2009+, where `Char` is `WideChar`.

Comment: All functions from OpenProcess to SendMessage, inclusive, run without errors. I indicated that new items are added to the tree, but they have no text and I do not know how to change icons. That was my question.

Comment: You don't know whether or not they run without error because there is no error checking

Comment: Please edit your question this time instead of creating a new ([linking your old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65414469/add-fake-device-to-windows-device-manager)).